# Sitecore commands with autofac

Tags: command, sitecore, scheduling

I have created a sitecore command which triggers an index rebuild.
I would like to be able to inject services with autofac.
Therefore I have followed this tutorial : http://maze-dev.blogspot.be/2014/03/dependency-injection-in-custom-sitecore.html

After having everything in place, it seems like the sitecore scheduling task tries to create a new instance of this command. While these already injected in the commandconfiguration class.

Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a Sitecore scheduled task runs in a separate thread, and since the command is registered as InstancePerLifetimeScope (if following the example in the linked blog post), Autofac will inject a new instance in the scheduled task.

Instead, in your scheduled task you should probably get the command from the CommandManager, using something like:

```
var command = CommandManager.GetCommand("mynamespance:mycategory:mycommand");
```

and then call Execute on the command.

Now, since the CommandConfigurator at bootstrap time registers the resolved command instance in the static CommandManager, the instance can effectively be seen as a singleton, and it should be available fully injected in the scheduled task (if the command is retrieved through the CommandManager, that is.) If the command is also executed from elsewhere in your Sitecore solution, it will most likely be on another thread. In that case it is probably a good idea to consider if your command implementation is thread safe.